# Magento2 where state/regions are stored

Tags: magento2, registry, state

Hello in Magento2 where is the xml file that stores the state/regions we believe "California" is being saved when customers place an order as "Cal" and we need to confirm if this is how Magento has the abbreviation for California and if so change it to CA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In magento region is not saved in `xml` it's stored in database table named `directory_country_region`

Comment: How 'safe' would it be to eliminate rows that are not enabled in the store, so they wouldn't show on the frontend? Such as certain US States/Regions like "Samoa"